# AES Encryption - Encryption/Decryption Adding Extra Bytes

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm writing a simple library for encryption/decryption, using the Framework's objects. The methods are as follows:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] vector, byte[] input)
{
    if(key.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt with empty key");

    if (vector.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt with empty vector");

    if (input.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt empty input");

    var unencryptedBytes = input;

    using(AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider {Key = key, IV = vector})
    using(ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (CryptoStream writer = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        writer.Write(unencryptedBytes, 0, unencryptedBytes.Length);
        writer.FlushFinalBlock();
        var byteArray = ms.ToArray();

        if(byteArray.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("Attempted to encrypt but encryption resulted in a byte array of 0 length.");

        return byteArray;
    }
}


public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] vector, byte[] encrypted)
{
    if (key.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt with empty key");

    if (vector.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt with empty vector");

    if (encrypted == null || encrypted.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot decrypt empty or null byte array");

    byte[] unencrypted;

    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider { Key = key, IV = vector })
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, vector))
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {

        cs.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);

        unencrypted =  ms.ToArray();
    }


    return unencrypted;
}
```

Feeding it in an encoded string, for example, as follows:

```
var expected = "This is an example message";

var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expected);
```

Goes in as (in this example) 26 bytes. After encryption it leaves as 32 bytes, and when this is translated back as a string it has random characters appended at the end but is otherwise perfectly valid, as follows:

```
"This is an example message�(4���"
```

Generating a new vector/key changes the random characters that are appended to the end.

How can I eliminate this extra-byte behavior?

**EDIT**

Included a requested unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanEncryptAndDecryptByteArray()
{
    var expected = "This is an example message";

    var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expected);


    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aes.GenerateIV();
    aes.GenerateKey();


    var byteKey = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
    var vectorKey = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV);

    var key = Convert.FromBase64String("Qcf+3VzYNAfPUCfBO/ePSxCLBLItkVfk8ajK86KYebs=");
    var vector = Convert.FromBase64String("aJNKWP7M2D44jilby6BzGg==");

    var encrypted = EncryptionManager.Encrypt(key, vector, messageBytes);
    var decrypted = EncryptionManager.Decrypt(key, vector, encrypted);

    var actual = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to encrypt/decrypt? In particular, something we can copy & paste to get the exact result you are (including key/vector)?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow, @Rob, those are literally the methods that encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a snippet of code which uses these two methods to encrypt and decrypt the string, including your current `key` and `vector` values.

Comment: Modified/cleaned up the unit test I was using and posted it. Same behavior with the unit test, so it should be fairly plug-and-play except for tossing my methods in a static class so you can call them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The junk-bytes are because we're reading and writing to the same array.

`new MemoryStream(encrypted))` Is telling the crypt to read from `encrypted`.

`cs.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);` Is telling it to write to `encrypted`.

The solution:

```
using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider { Key = key, IV = vector })
using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, vector))
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    var decrypted = new byte[encrypted.Length];
    var bytesRead = cs.Read(decrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);    

    return decrypted.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();
}
```

Note that we take `bytesRead` from the array, rather than the full array, as we would otherwise end up with null bytes (which fail a string comparison but appear identical in editors)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help, Rob. This is a beautiful, and simple solution that exactly fixes the problem.

Comment: @NexTerren No worries mate, glad it helped :)

Comment: @NexTerren Turns out I completely mis-read the MemoryStream creation. The core of the problem is completely different - I've edited the post to provide a more reliable solution. I initially thought the library was writing junk-bytes to the end of the array (rather than the junk bytes actually coming from the input! :))

Comment: So your original solution worked with all of the unit tests, but your new solution does *not* work; extra characters are back to being tacked on. Are you sure about the change, @Rob?

Comment: @NexTerren Can you give me an input string which this is failing for?

Comment: The unit test--exactly as is--fails with your modification, but passes for your original solution. Your modification produces the string: "This is an example message\0\0\0\0\0\0"

Comment: @NexTerren Sorry - my bad, my editor does not show null bytes. See update (again, we take the correct amount of bytes, but it should be a lot more stable by reading and writing to the correct arrays now)

Comment: And again to working flawlessly, and I'll take the increased stability! Thanks once more, @Rob.

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The AES encryption is a [block encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with block size of 16 bytes (128-bit) [note: the key size can of 128-bit, 192-bit or 256-bit, but the data block size is of multiplication of 16 bytes]. Thus, to use AES, the resulting encrypted message will be multiplication of 16 - and cannot be otherwise.

To decrypt it, you may want to get rid of the extra bytes it causes too.

1. One way to do this is by append header in your message, stating how many bytes the message is. Then in the decrypt side, you read this header and cut the number of bytes

   ```
   [header = value of 26] + [message]
   ```
2. Alternatively, you could append some extra bytes at the end of your encrypted message

   ```
   [message][append with 000000] //to make up the block, such that the message length will be of multiplication of 16
   ```

Of the two methods above, I personally prefer the first one since it is much clearer, while the second one assumes you receive certain text pattern which is impossible to get concatenated 0000 at the end.

I am not aware if there is a way to solve this issue apart from the two given ways above - implicitly (such as using [CryptoStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx)) or explicitly.

Comment: Assuming the code is unaware of the message's length when getting the encrypted value, how would removing the extra bytes work? Is it something that can be calculated? I'm not only planning on using this for strings, mind; any byte array should be able to be encrypted.

Comment: As far as I know, people solve this in two ways: (1) add header to state the number of bytes (2) append `00000` at the end of the text to make up the remaining bytes, making it multiplication of 16. I am not aware of the way to do this otherwise, given the nature of AES encryption itself

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and upvote you, but wait around a day or two and see if a better answer appears before accepting it. I don't like hauling around/inserting metadata into arguments, but if this is the way to fix the issue I'll go ahead with it.

Comment: @NexTerren see Rob answer. I think that is what you look for.

Answer (score 1):

AES encryption does the encryption in 16, 24 or 32 byte (or 128, 192 or 256 bits) blocks. So the data you get back is just random data packed onto the end.

You'll have to prepend your data with a couple of bytes to represent the actual legnth:

```
var length = new byte [] { (byte) ((unencryptedBytes.Length >> 8) & 0xff) ,
    (byte) (unencryptedBytes.Length & 0xff);
writer.Write(length, 0, length.Length); 
writer.Write(unencryptedBytes, 0, unencryptedBytes.Length);
writer.FlushFinalBlock();
```

and then in the reader retrieve the length:

```
unencrypted =  ms.ToArray();

int length = ((int) unencrypted[0] << 8) + unencrypted[1];

var result = new byte[length];

unencrypted.CopyTo(result, 2, 0, length);

return result;
```

Comment: Note that the key size can be of 128-bit, 192-bit, or 256-bit. But the block (data) size is always 128-bit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard